# Налаживать повязки или накладывать повязки?

Tags: лексика, грамматика

Учитель прислал такое сообщение: « Сегодня, 21 июня, в 5 отряде был медицинский час, на котором Елена Николаевна показывала, как правильно налаживать повязки, ведь не всегда с нами рядом взрослые, нужно и самим уметь!»

Правильно ли здесь употребляется глагол «налаживать»? Или правильно все-таки накладывать повязки? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У совершённо глагола ‟наложить” есть значение покрыть поверхность чем-то, а у несовершённого глагола ‟налаживать” нет такого значения. Чтобы обозначить такое несовершённое действие используют глагол ‟накладывать”. А с ‟накладывать” всё наоборот – если нужно обозначить такое совершённое действие, то используют ‟наложить”.

‟Налаживать” неправильно здесь употребляется, нужно использовать ‟накладывать”.